# Collections.binarySearch() vs. List indexOf()

Tags: java, algorithm, list, collections

I have a list of more than 37K items, and I already implemented `hashCode()`, `equals()`, so I wonder `Collections.binarySearch()` can help improve the performance and faster than `indexOf()` method.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If your collection is sorted, `binarySearch()` will be O(log n) as opposed to `indexOf()`'s O(n) and you will definitely see an improvement.

Comment: This is true only if the collection allows constant time-complexity random access, eg ArrayList. It is not true for a LinkedList.

Answer (score 10):

in order for binarySearch() to work, your list must be sorted.  equals() and hashCode() have nothing to do with sorting.  your objects need to be Comparable, or you must have a relevant Comparator.  either way, you *must* sort the List first.

and yes, assuming the list is sorted, then you will probably get better performance from binarySearch() as compared to indexOf().

Comment: Actually, my items also are Comparable.

Answer (score 3):

You'll get even better performance by using a HashSet. That will take more space, though.